# Docker File and Python

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, fastapi, uvicorn

Apologies I am very new to Docker.  I have the following `Docker` file which contains the following commands (see below). I am not sure I understand all commands and I would appreciate some explanation. I commented all the lines I understood but put a question mark in others. Please see below

```
#That this line means that python will be our base. Can some comment here please and explain this line more?
FROM python:3.9 as base
 
#create a working directory in the virtual machine (VM)
WORKDIR /code    

# copy all the python requirements stored in requirements.txt into the new directoy (in the VM)
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt    


# activate the package manager pip. But why use no-cache-dir?
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

# copy all files to the new directory (in the VM)
COPY ./ /code/

# I don't understand the line below. Please explain? why uvicorn? app.main:app is the 
 #location of the fastapi
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "180"]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Docker file states all steps that Docker will execute when creating your image. From that image, a container can be created.

```
#That this line means that python will be our base. Can some comment here please and explain this line more?
FROM python:3.9 as base
```

This is very basic docker stuff, follow a (beginners) tutorial and you will learn a lot more than just someone spoon-feeding little bits of knowledge.

```
#create a working directory in the virtual machine (VM)
WORKDIR /code
```

You are creating a container image, not a VM. That is a similar but very different concept and should not be mixed.

```
# copy all the python requirements stored in requirements.txt into the new directoy (in the VM)
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
```

This copies all files to the **image**.

```
# activate the package manager pip. But why use no-cache-dir?
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
```

RUN is an image build step, and the outcome will be committed to the Docker image. So, in this step, you are telling docker that you want an image that has everything installed as outlined in `requirements.txt` with `pip`. No cache, by default PIP saves the whl's of the packages you are installing, but that only would increase the image and are no longer required. So, no cache.

```
# copy all files to the new directory (in the VM)
COPY ./ /code/
```

Again, not VM but **image**, an image that will later be used to create a container.

```
# I don't understand the line below. Please explain? why uvicorn? app.main:app is the 
 #location of the fastapi
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "180"]
```

Because you are trying to run a FastAPI project, and FastAPI is just the app; you need a server to actually be able to fire request at FastAPI. [This is explained on the very first page of the FastAPI documentation actually.](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read the intro course to FastApi but i am not fully there yet for Docker. Thanks again for the detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

"app.main:app" express your project has such python file:

```
<Project Root Dir>
   app - folder
     main.py -- python file
```

In the `main.py`, you init a FastAPI instance and named `app`, like this:

```
# main.py
....
app = FastAPI()
...
```

`unicorn` use above rules to get the FastAPI instance `app`, then load it.